# Call Class Methods passed as parameter

Tags: java, function

It's kinda hard to explain the problem so I will explain with the code below.
I would like to create the method applyAll.
applyAll take a setter method from the User class and call a function (passed as parameter) to set value of that method.

Problems are:

- what is the type of User::setLogin ?
- how can I call this generic method ?

```java
public class UserBuilder {
    private List<User> users;

    /* ... */

    public <T> UserBuilder applyAll(??? method, Function<Integer, T> func) {
        for (int index = 0; index < users.size(); index++) {
            // I don't know how to call 'method' parameter (which is a method of User class)
            users.get(i)[method](func.apply(index));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder withLogin(Function<Integer, String> func) {
        return applyAll(User::setLogin, func);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

```java
public class User {
    private String login;

    void setLogin(String login) { this.login = login; }
}
```

Example of use case:

```java
List<User> users = new UserBuilder(10).withLogin((index) -> "user_" + index).build();
```

Comment: "what is the type of User::setLogin ?" we can't know without seeing its declaration. But since you use it as an array index, the only thing it could be is an `int`, but a method reference cannot be an `int`. Do you mean `method.apply(users.get(i))` or something?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing `Method` (which is a description of a method in reflection) with a "method reference" (which is a way to represent a method as a lambda).

Comment: Yes the type Method is confusing, I changed it by "???" because I don't know which type User::setLogin refers to.
I also added the User class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `User::setLogin` can resolve into a `java.util.function.BiConsumer<User, T>`:

```java
public <T> UserBuilder applyAll(BiConsumer<User, T> setter, Function<Integer, T> func) {
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        setter.accept(users.get(i), func.apply(i));
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The setter that is relevant here must clearly 'take' one parameter, of type `T` (after all, that's what you pass to it in your example code - the result of `func.apply(index)`, which is an instance of T), and which returns - well, nothing. It's a setter.

Thus, it's a `java.util.function.Consumer<T>` - a method that takes Ts and produces nothing - that 'consumes Ts'. To be perfectly correct, it'd be allright if the setter consumes some supertype of Ts just as well (if your function produces Integers, and your setter accepts Numbers - that's okay). So let's make that `Consumer<? super T>`.

```
public <T> UserBuilder applyAll(Consumer<? super T> setter, Function<Integer, T> func) {
 ...
}
```

and you can call it:

```
List<String> names = ....;
Function<Integer, String> nameMaker = idx -> names.get(idx);
builder.applyAll(User::setName, nameMaker);
```